# MongoDB docs $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

I have a document in MongoDB:

```
student{
    id: ...id
    name: ...
    student:[{ 
        group_number: ...
        results:[{subj: ... , mark: 5},{...},{...}]
    }]

}
```

And I need to use

```
db.student.aggregate({$group: {_id : "$_id", 
                               mark_total : {$sum : $student.results.mark}}
```

})

the problem is that $student.results.mark returns undefined so aggregate returns

```
"result":[
    {
    "_id" : 2,
    "mark_total: : 0
    }
 ],
"ok" : 1
```

as  $sum return nothing

What do you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `student.results` is a array, access its with `$student.results.mark` returns nothing, that's used for access field of embedded document.
You will need to make each element of the element to become embedded element first with `$unwind` stage

Sample data

```
db.student.insert([{
    name: 'Foo',
    student:[{ 
        group_number: 1,
        results:[{subj: 'Math', mark: 5}, {subj: 'Info', mark: 4}, {subj: 'English', mark: 3}]
    }]
 }])
```

Final Query

```
db.student.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$student" },
    { "$unwind": "$student.results" },
    { "$group": { _id: "$_id", mark_total: { $sum: "$student.results.mark" } } }
]);
```

Final Output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566790f6e1f3a57c81bdf2f9"), "mark_total" : 12 }
```

Because `student` field is an array, the first stage `{ "$unwind": "$student" }` will make `{ group_number: 1, results:[{subj: 'Math', mark: 5}, {subj: 'Info', mark: 4}, {subj: 'English', mark: 3}]}` to become embedded document.
Output after first `$unwind` stage

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566790f6e1f3a57c81bdf2f9"), "name" : "Foo", "student" : { "group_number" : 1, "results" : [ { "subj" : "Math", "mark" : 5 }, { "subj" : "Info", "mark" : 4 }, { "subj" : "English", "mark" : 3 } ] } }
```

Then you need to unwind again because "$student.results" is still an array
Output after 2nd unwind

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566790f6e1f3a57c81bdf2f9"), "name" : "Foo", "student" : { "group_number" : 1, "results" : { "subj" : "Math", "mark" : 5 } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566790f6e1f3a57c81bdf2f9"), "name" : "Foo", "student" : { "group_number" : 1, "results" : { "subj" : "Info", "mark" : 4 } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566790f6e1f3a57c81bdf2f9"), "name" : "Foo", "student" : { "group_number" : 1, "results" : { "subj" : "English", "mark" : 3 } } }
```

You can now access the mark with "$student.results.mark"

Comment: thank you,it helped a lot!
But what if I'll have hundreds of subjects so after unwind my document will weight more than 16 Mb and mongoDB will return errror exceeds maximum size. What shall I do? Use GridFS API ?

Comment: i think you mistake some thing, unwind stage split the big document onto multi smaller one, so the size each small document is much less than the big one. Also, during the processing stage, documents may exceed the limit 16mb (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/)